# Seeking Unification Algorithm in F#

Tags: f#, unification

I am transforming ASTs and need more than simple pattern matching, thus the unification algorithm.

While this is for a .NET project and I know that I could just interoperate with a .NET PROLOG implementation, I only need to embed the unification algorithm; so PROLOG is overkill.

If I could get "Martelli, Montanari: An Efficient Unification Algorithm" written in F# that would be perfect, but I will settle for it any functional language including HASKELL and translate to F#.

Comment: It might be rough-going, but have you checked the [F# source](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp)? Alternatively, you can buy the [article you referenced](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=357169).

Comment: @Daniel There is probably no need to buy the article from ACM as it is available for free online (e.g. http://www.nsl.com/misc/papers/martelli-montanari.pdf). But AFAIK, this is a standard unification algorithm and is well documented on WikiPedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_algorithm

Comment: @GuyCoder - if you have a problem just post a new question - the idea of Stack Overflow is that someone else can learn from what you are doing

Comment: @TomasPetricek As far as I'm concerned what you can find on Wikipedia is an exponential Robinson algorithm. It's still used as it performs well in the real-world. The article however certainly describes something more sophisticated. There are linear time and almost linear time algorithms available: Baxter, Paterson-Wegman, etc. There's a good survey by Kevin Knight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it is a good practice to share your attempts when asking questions on SO. People will not generally give you a complete solution for your problems - just answers when you have specific question or hints how to approach the problem.

So, I'll share some hints about the general approach, but it is **not a complete solution**.
First you need to represent your AST in some way. In F#, you can do that using discriminated unions. The following supports variables, values and function applications:

```
type Expr =
  | Function of string * Expr list
  | Variable of string
  | Value of int
```

Unification is a function that takes list of expressions to be unified of type `(Expr * Expr) list` and returns assignments to variables (assigning an expression `Expr` to a variable name `string`):

```
let rec unify exprs =
  match exprs with 
  // Unify two variables - if they are equal, we continue unifying 
  // the rest of the constraints, otherwise the algorithm fails
  | (Variable s1, Variable s2)::remaining ->
      if s1 = s2 then unify remaining
      else failwith "cannot unify variables"
  // Unify variable with some other expression - unify the remaining
  // constraints and add new assignment to the result
  | (Variable s, expr)::remaining 
  | (expr, Variable s)::remaining  ->
      let rest = unify remaining
      // (s, expr) is a tuple meaning that we assign 'expr' to variable 's'
      (s, expr)::rest

  // TODO: Handle remaining cases here!
  | _ -> failwith "cannot unify..."
```

There are a few cases that you'll need to add. Most importantly, unifying `Function` with `Function` means that you need to check that the function names are the same (otherwise fail) and then add all argument expressions as new constraints to the `remaining` list...

Comment: @GuyCoder No problem - that sounds like you're looking for existing implementation that you could use - I'm not aware of any (simple and extensible) code that you could re-use, but building on my sample, it shouldn't be too difficult to complete it.

Comment: @GuyCoder It is a bit unfortunate that you cannot use discriminated unions - wrapping the ANTLR CommonTree in active patterns so that you get nice pattern matching in F# sounds like a way to go!

Answer (score 3):

The final syntactic unification in Baader & Snyder uses union-find to partition the nodes of the two structures into equivalence classes. It then walks those classes building up the triangular substitution.

Since it uses union-find, if you're looking for a purely functional answer you're out of luck; no-one knows how to write a functional union-find. However, we know how to write a persistent union-find which is at least *apparently* functional, thanks to [Conchon and Filliâtre](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/ftp/publis/puf-wml07.ps) (written in OCaml).

Comment: I'm surprised at the downvote: the link is to an OCaml implementation of half of Martelli-Montanari's algorithm.